# How to call function defined in template

Tags: c++

I'm in the process of trying to find a polynomial regression for a set of x and y data. I downloaded the template below to do so, but I have no idea how to call it, and my attempts are met with error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol.

```
#pragma once

#ifdef BOOST_UBLAS_TYPE_CHECK
#   undef BOOST_UBLAS_TYPE_CHECK
#endif
#define BOOST_UBLAS_TYPE_CHECK 0
#ifndef _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#   define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#endif

#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/lu.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

/*
Finds the coefficients of a polynomial p(x) of degree n that fits the data, 
p(x(i)) to y(i), in a least squares sense. The result p is a row vector of 
length n+1 containing the polynomial coefficients in incremental powers.

param:
    oX              x axis values
    oY              y axis values
    nDegree         polynomial degree including the constant

return:
    coefficients of a polynomial starting at the constant coefficient and
    ending with the coefficient of power to nDegree. C++0x-compatible 
    compilers make returning locally created vectors very efficient.

*/
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> polyfit( const std::vector<T>& oX, 
const std::vector<T>& oY, int nDegree )
{
...
}
```

I don't think ya'll need the rest of the template to help me out, but I will post it if necessary. (It's from this site http://vilipetek.com/2013/10/07/polynomial-fitting-in-c-using-boost/) If there's a better/easier tool out there, let me know about it.

This is how I tried to run it: 
Declaration

```
std::vector<int> polyfit( const std::vector<int> xsplinevector, 
                   const std::vector<int> ysplinevector,
```

function call

```
polynomial = polyfit((xsplinevector), (ysplinevector), 4);
               int nDegree );
```

Comment: Why are you re-declaring it? That has the effect of declaring a specialization that you don't implement, hence unresolved symbol.

Comment: @tadman perhaps that is the wrong term. In order to use a method inside another one, do you not have to have the method's header above?

Comment: Which error (a complete description of it)?

Comment: Declaring the definition and implementation of the template version in the header should be sufficient. Re-declaring confuses things.

Comment: @user3241316: In case of a template, you in fact need the whole template (the definition). Not just the prototype (declaration). But even if you intended to provide a declaration, it should still match the definition. And thus the declaration should be a template, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <polyfit.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> xsplinevector;
    std::vector<int> ysplinevector;
    std::vector<int> poly;

    // fill both xsplinevector and ysplinevector

    poly = polyfit(xsplinevector, ysplinevector, 4);

}
```

Comment: I was making it quite a bit more complicated than necessary. This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your (explicit) function call should be:

```
polynomial = polyfit<int>((xsplinevector), (ysplinevector), 4);
```

And don't re-declare the function with the `int` templated type, that's probably what is causing your error.

Comment: No need for the `<int>`, it's a deduced context.

Comment: That's why I said **explicit** function call.

Answer (score 0):

Since you define the templated function as follows:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> polyfit( const std::vector<T>& oX, 
const std::vector<T>& oY, int nDegree )
{
...
}
```

When using it, the template argument needs to appear after the function name. In the case of classes, you would do:

```
myClass<int> someVariable;
```

In the case of functions you would do:

```
myFunction<int>();
```

So, in your particular case:

```
vector<int> polynomial;
polynomial = polyfit<int>((xsplinevector), (ysplinevector), 4);
```

Comment: Not necessary. Function Template Arguments can often be deduced, and this is not an exception. Class template arguments can't be deduced, that's why we have functions like `std::make_pair` to deduce a `std::pair` type.